# Real Time application with django and python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using Django 1.6 and python 3.2 for my project and I need some help.
Currently I'm working on a notification system and the performance is terrifying. Right now I send ajax request on every 2 seconds, and in case there is new notification for this user in the datebase, just increase the count of the unread notifications with 1. This just works fine, but I don't think that this will be useful, when the project goes live.
I've looked for the solution in SO and Google, but nothing useful found. Actually I've found some good modules (https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/real-time/), but all of them are for python 2.
So can you please share with me your experience with real time application, suggest some ported for python 3 modules and what will be the easiest solution on this case.

Comment: You should share some more requirements of yours, eg. which protocols you need to use, eg if you need some full solution with lots of fallbacks like socketio, or maybe even just websockets is fine for you. Wouldnt spend too much hope on finding something that is proven to work with Python 3, guess in any case you maybe would have to adpot a package of your choice to work with Python 3 or go back to Python 2.7...

Comment: @BernhardVallant - Thank you for your response and advice. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with how the sockets works and don't have any idea which protocols I need. The project should be written in Python 3 and I don't have the option to change the version to Python 2. The only thing I want is to increase the count dynamically, without ajax requests. I already think about the option to port one of them to Python 3, but most of them are based on gevent, which I don't think that will be easy to port for Python 3.

Comment: unrelated: have you read this [primer on real time web in Python](http://mrjoes.github.io/2013/06/21/python-realtime.html)?

Comment: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html, https://twistedmatrix.com